# Evaluate classification model's ability to dicriminate between different ranges of the outcome label

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I would like to evaluate my model's ability to discriminate between people with prediabetes (hba1c 5.7-6.4%) and diabetes type 2 (hba1c > 6.4%)

My outcome label (y_test) is hba1c>5.7%, defining unhealthy people with undiagnosed diabetes or prediabetic conditions.

How do I separate the two ranges, compare the predicted values with actual values and calculate the sensitivity?

The present example is according to the logistic regression model.

````
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)

X_train = X_train[feat_cols]
X_test = X_test[feat_cols]

# Building LGR and evaluating on training data
LGR = LogisticRegression(max_iter=100, random_state=1)



def evaluate_model(LGR, X_test, y_test):
  
    # Predict Test Data 
    y_pred = LGR.predict(X_test)

    # Calculate accuracy, precision, sensitivity and specificity
    acc = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    prec = metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
    sen = metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred, pos_label=1)
    spe = metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred, pos_label=0)

    # Calculate area under curve (AUC)
    y_pred_proba = LGR.predict_proba(X_test)[::,1]
    fpr, tpr, _ = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_proba)
    auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_proba)

    # Display confussion matrix
    cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

    return {'acc': acc, 'prec': prec, 'sen': sen, 'spe': spe,
            'fpr': fpr, 'tpr': tpr, 'auc': auc, 'cm': cm}


LGR_eval = evaluate_model(LGR, X_test, y_test)

# Print result
print('Accuracy:', LGR_eval['acc'])
print('Precision:', LGR_eval['prec'])
print('Sensitivity:', LGR_eval['sen'])
print('Specificity:', LGR_eval['spe'])
print('Area Under Curve:', LGR_eval['auc'])
print('Confusion Matrix:\n', LGR_eval['cm'])```

Accuracy: 0.7315175097276264
Precision: 0.711340206185567
Sensitivity: 0.7439353099730458
Specificity: 0.72
Area Under Curve: 0.8036994609164421
Confusion Matrix:
 [[288 112]
 [ 95 276]]
````

Comment: Is your question regarding splitting your test dataset into 3 different labels? (healthy, prediabetic and type 2?) Or what more exactly do you have trouble with?

Comment: Sorry if the question is not entirely understandable. I have made feature selection and trained and evaluated my models with a binary output, healthy (hba1c<5.7) or unhealthy (hba1c>5.7%). The unhealthy population contains two diabetic conditions; thus, I want to know if my performance metrics will be generalized for prediabetes (hba1c 5.7-6,7%) and type 2 (hba1c>6.4%) or if the models are better at predicting only one of the two conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering comment above)

As you do not use a linear output but the logistical regression it will be difficult to achieve what you ask for without making quite some changes.

Either you change your model to a linear regression model and predict the hbac-value and after that just classify the prediction in the < 5.7, 5.7 - 6.4 range or > 6.4 range. This way you can use your metrics which you've used above.

The other way around is dependant on the Y dataset, does it contain any labels regarding the different conditions or is it just labeled healthy / unhealthy? If you were to add another label which corresponds to the values (alot like above) then you can turn your model to an multi-output prediction model and still use the logistical regression, and then investigate your metrics for the requested classes.

---

Edit in response to comment:
Below is the function from comments.

```
def IsAtRisk(x):
    if x < 5.7:
        return 0      
    return 1 

df['IsAtRisk'] = df['LBXGH'].map(IsAtRisk)
print(df) 
print(f"{len(df[df['IsAtRisk'] == True])} of {len(df)} people are at risk")
```

If you instead include the range that you ask for and apply another class you'll have the labels for the diffrent classes and can measure with the metrics regarding how the model performs.

```
def IsAtRisk(x):
    if x < 5.7:
        return 0
    elif 5.7 < x < 6.4:
        return 1
    return 2
```

But for this to work you should most likely format the samples in a different way depending on your model structure. If you would share your model structure and the output-layer it would help.

Most likely you will want to restructure your Y labels to

```
y_sample = [1, 0, 0] # This is the probability 1 of class 0 which may be the health individuals in your dataset

# With this in mind you can correct the return values from the above function to return arrays of the labels instead of ints.
```

Comment: Changing models is not possible because the thesis is completed and signed in.

There might be a chance that the model is performing better at predicting type 2 than prediabetes. Thus it would be interesting to investigate the true positive rate according to healthy vs. prediabetes and healthy vs. type 2.
I thought it would be possible to separate those predicted healthy (0's) and unhealthy (1's). And in some way, range the unhealthy by the hba1c, separate prediabetes (hba1c 5.7-6.4) from type 2 (hba1c>6.4%), and measure the difference in true positive rate according to the two conditions?

Comment: It all depends on how the label data is formatted, is it labeld by the numerical range or by booleans?

Comment: The original label is floating numbers according to the subject's actual hba1c values. The y_test label is boolean.

`def IsAtRisk(x):
  if x < 5.7:
    return 0
  
  return 1`

`df['IsAtRisk'] = df['LBXGH'].map(IsAtRisk)

print(df)
print(f"{len(df[df['IsAtRisk'] == True])} of {len(df)} people are at risk")`


4334 of 13504 people are at risk

Comment: Edited my previous response with some notes, please look at them and get back to me if they do not make sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help. The code is updated with the model structure. However, I'm not quite sure about the output layer?

Comment: Is it this model that you are using?:https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html If so is the case, then you can set the `multi_class` parameter accordingly to the documentation for multiple ouputs. I have not used the mode previously but either you will get a single value as prediction or 3 values as predictions. If it's 1, that is the class with highest probability. If you get 3 there will be a probability distribution for each class, so pick the index with highest value.